# Python: Strange hanging behavior when piping large stdout of a subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I am currently calling `ffmpeg` to extract a binary data stream from a video file, and then putting that binary data into a list. There is a lot of data in this data stream, about 4,000 kb. Here is the code

```
# write and call ffmpeg command, piping stdout
cmd = "ffmpeg -i video.mpg -map 0:1 -c copy -f data -"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# read from stdout, byte by byte
li = []
for char in iter(lambda: proc.stdout.read(1), ""):
    li.append(char)
```

This works fine. However, if I take out the part where I am reading from `stdout`, it starts working but then hangs:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i video.mpg -map 0:1 -c copy -f data -"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
```

I had to add `time.sleep(10)` at the end or else the process would end before the `subprocess`, causing this error:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ove
rhead: 0.000000%
Conversion failed!
```

Calling either `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` or `subprocess.call(cmd)` also cause hanging (the latter just displays the `stdout` in the console while the former doesn't).

Is there something about reading from `stdout` that prevents this hanging (like perhaps the buffer getting cleared), or am I unknowingly introducing a bug elsewhere? I'm worried that such a small change causes the program to break; it doesn't inspire very much confidence.

The other issue with this code is that I need to read from the list from another thread. This might mean I need to use a `Queue`. But when I execute the below code, it takes 11 seconds as opposed to 3 seconds with the list equivalent:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i video.mpg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -map 0:1 -c copy -f data -"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

q = Queue()

for char in iter(lambda: proc.stdout.read(1), ""):
    q.put(char)
```

Should I be using another data structure?

Comment: Not sure, but try to add option -nostdin

Comment: Good idea to add -nostdin since it's a subprocess. Didn't fix this issue, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reading data from the pipe one byte at a time is really inefficient. You should read bigger chunks.
2. Executing the subprocess and then terminating the parent without waiting for the child to finish will cause a broken pipe error and the subprocess will fail, as you noticed.
3. Calling `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` will block/stall the writer if the OS buffer gets filled (ie. if you don't read from the pipe like in your case).
4. `Queue` is fine as long as you don't read one byte at a time

Comment: The reason I read one byte at a time is because I decode the data one byte at a time. I'll try to think of a better way to do that.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem while simply trying to pipe raw 8bit pixel values to a c++ application, it works for the first ~53.5 or so frames and then just hangs with the same error as the user in this post. _(this just in the terminal, no fancy sub processes)_

I have two questions:

1. Why is reading data from a pipe 1 byte at a time inefficient?
2. What is the optimal amount of bytes to read from a pipe at a time? _(could I read 64 bytes in one go given 8x8 grayscale images?)_

Comment: @memeko It was inefficient in the context of the original question as video frame sizes are way larger, so read as much as it makes sense. If you get an error you might have a different issue.