# FFMPEG error with Python Popen on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, popen

I'm trying to extract key-frames from a video called "twws.mp4" using FFMPEG and Python's Popen. However, I'm getting some error. This error has popped up recently.

I've been using https://github.com/chexov/image2pipe repository for frame extraction. However, even the examples mentioned in this code have stopped working.

```py
    cmd = "ffmpeg -v error -skip_frame nokey -i twws.mp4 -vsync 0 -r 30 -s 
    300x300 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f image2pipe -"

    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    frame_ext_proc = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,bufsize=10**8)
```

The error I received is as follows:

```
  File ".\test.py", line 97, in <module>
    decoder.start()
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'images_from_url.<locals>.<lambda>'
PS C:\Users\g_host\Desktop\wxTest> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\g_host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
    Last message repeated 3 times
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065496/python-strange-hanging-behavior-when-piping-large-stdout-of-a-subprocess)?

Comment: @Selcuk I just went through that question. The problem in my case is limited to Windows. I tried executing the same command on Linux and it worked. Also, I'm following all the suggestions mentioned on that post.